# C# - Pegar um valor especifico do combobox - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Estou tentando pegar um valor especifico de um combobox, porém não sei como fazer isso, no exemplo abaixo em passo uma consulta a esse combobox.

```
                        var ConsultaservicosJsonString = await
                            response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var data = (from servicos in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Servico
                        []>(ConsultaservicosJsonString)
                                    where servicos.status_del_lgo.Equals("V")
                                    && servicos.situacao.Equals("D")
                                    orderby servicos.cod_svrs
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        CODIGO = servicos.cod_svrs,
                                        NUMERO = servicos.nr_servico,
                                        DESCRIÇÃO = servicos.descricao,
                                        VALOR = servicos.valor
                                    }).ToList();
                        txtServPedido.ValueMember = "CODIGO";
                        txtServPedido.DisplayMember = "DESCRIÇÃO";
                        txtServPedido.DataSource = data;
```

E nesse caso abaixo eu tento buscar um dos valores que passei, que seria "VALOR", eu encontro ele quando utilizo o SelectedItem, porém não consigo passar somente esse valor para uma variável... tentei de algumas formas, porém não consegui...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
private void txtItemPedido_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var teste2 = txtItemPedido.SelectedText.ToString();
        //string teste3 = Convert.ToString(txtItemPedido.FindStringExact("VALOR"));
        decimal selectedvl = (decimal)txtItemPedido.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Segue o erro que ocorre quando tento da forma orientada abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O `SelectedValue` será o valor de "CODIGO", o `SelectedText`, DESCRIÇÃO e `SelectedItem` será um objeto anônimo `{ CODIGO, NUMERO, DESCRICAO, VALOR }`.  Basta escolher qual deles você vai usar

Comment: Então, mas qual seria a sintaxe para que eu consiga passar esse valor para uma variável?

Comment: `string codigo = txtItemPedido.SelectedValue?.ToString();` ou `var item = txtItemPedido.SelectedItem;` -> `decimal valor = item.VALOR`

Comment: O primeiro código retornou o valor de "1", no segundo pego o erro CS1061, infelizmente também não deu certo...

**Erro CS1061** ‘object’ não contém uma definição para "VALOR" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "VALOR" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo ‘object’ (você está se esquecendo de usar uma diretiva ou uma referência de assembly?)

Comment: Adicionei uma print do erro na pergunta.

Comment: Eu só tinha feito um teste com o tipo anônimo no fiddle o que acabou sendo diferente que usar no linq... A resposta do André explica e dá a solução perfeitamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annonymous types tem métodos como escopo, portanto não deveriam ser usados fora do escopo do método onde você os declara.

Uma solução sem usar annonymous types seria declarar um type explicitamente:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
    public int CODIGO { get; set; }
    public string NUMERO { get; set; }
    public string DESCRICAO { get; set; }
    public float VALOR { get; set; }
}
```

Na sua linq query:

```
var data = (from servicos in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Servico
    []>(ConsultaservicosJsonString)
                where servicos.status_del_lgo.Equals("V")
                && servicos.situacao.Equals("D")
                orderby servicos.cod_svrs
                select new MinhaClasse
                {
                    CODIGO = servicos.cod_svrs,
                    NUMERO = servicos.nr_servico,
                    DESCRIÇÃO = servicos.descricao,
                    VALOR = servicos.valor
                }).ToList();
```

Quando você quiser obter o objeto selecionado, basta fazer o cast:

```
var minhaClasseSelecionado = txtItemPedido.SelectedItem as MinhaClasse;
```

Se por algum motivo você precisar usar um annonymous type nesse contexto, creio que a única solução seria usar reflection, algo como:

```
// Obtém o valor da propriedade VALOR
var itemSelecionado = txtItemPedido.SelectedItem;
itemSelecionado.GetType().GetProperty("VALOR").GetValue(itemSelecionado , null);
```

Comment: Deu certo cara, muito obrigado!